# Qt4 to Qt5: QPainter::drawPixmapFragments() with 5 arguments - how to solve?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4.8, qt5.4

Qt 4.8 (4.8.6) has a QPainter::drawPixmapFragments() overloaded function with 5 arguments:

```
void drawPixmapFragments(const QRectF *targetRects, const QRectF *sourceRects, int fragmentCount,
                         const QPixmap &pixmap, PixmapFragmentHints hints = 0);
```

Qt 5 (5.4.1) has no such function, it has only one (same as in Qt 4.8) with 4 arguments:

```
void drawPixmapFragments(const PixmapFragment *fragments, int fragmentCount,
                         const QPixmap &pixmap, PixmapFragmentHints hints = 0);
```

I've searched in `wiki.qt.io`, here on stackoverflow and several other places, but there is no answer how to port it from Qt 4.8 to Qt 5.

How to do it?

**UPD** I've taken realization from Qt 4.8.6 source (`qpainter.cpp`) and simply transform it to take pointer to QPainter as first parameter:

```
namespace oldqt
{
    void drawPixmapFragments(QPainter *painter, const QRectF *targetRects, const QRectF *sourceRects, int fragmentCount,
        const QPixmap &pixmap, QPainter::PixmapFragmentHints hints)
    {
        // Q_D(QPainter); 

        if (/* !d->engine || */ pixmap.isNull())
            return;

    #ifndef QT_NO_DEBUG
        if (sourceRects) {
            for (int i = 0; i < fragmentCount; ++i) {
                QRectF sourceRect = sourceRects[i];
                if (!(QRectF(pixmap.rect()).contains(sourceRect)))
                    qWarning("QPainter::drawPixmapFragments - the source rect is not contained by the pixmap's rectangle");
            }
        }
    #endif

    // if (d->engine->isExtended()) {
    //              d->extended->drawPixmapFragments(targetRects, sourceRects, fragmentCount, pixmap, hints);
    //          }
    //          else {
            if (sourceRects) {
                for (int i = 0; i < fragmentCount; ++i)
                    painter->drawPixmap(targetRects[i], pixmap, sourceRects[i]);
            }
            else {
                QRectF sourceRect = pixmap.rect();
                for (int i = 0; i < fragmentCount; ++i)
                    painter->drawPixmap(targetRects[i], pixmap, sourceRect);
            }
    //          }

    }
}
```

But I commented out some lines. `Q_D(QPainter)` somehow defines `d` from `d_func`, how can I take it from `*painter`? Or it is not possible?
May be there is another solution?

**UPD2** Example of my legacy code:

```
class ButtonSelector:public QGraphicsObject
// ...

void ButtonSelector::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    //painter->drawPixmap(m_backGnd.rect(), m_backGnd);
    QRectF rectSrc = QRectF(m_backGnd.rect());
    QRectF rectTrg = boundingRect();
    painter->drawPixmapFragments(&rectTrg,&rectSrc,1,m_backGnd, QPainter::OpaqueHint);
    // I've change it to this call:
    // oldqt::drawPixmapFragments(painter, &rectTrg, &rectSrc, 1, m_backGnd, QPainter::OpaqueHint);
    // where oldqt::drawPixmapFragments is function from above

    // ... some other code unrelated to the question
}
```

In principle, it works OK. What is incorrect in the code?

**Solution** Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232439/qt4-to-qt5-qpainterdrawpixmapfragments-with-5-arguments-how-to-solve-up/30234976#30234976) by [@amartel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2169277/amartel):

```
void drawPixmapFragments(QPainter *painter, const QRectF *targetRects, const QRectF *sourceRects, int fragmentCount,
    const QPixmap &pixmap, QPainter::PixmapFragmentHints hints)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < fragmentCount; ++i) {
        QRectF sourceRect = (sourceRects) ? sourceRects[i] : pixmap.rect();

        QPainter::PixmapFragment pixmapFragment =
            QPainter::PixmapFragment::create(
                targetRects[i].center(),
                sourceRects[i],
                targetRects[i].width() / sourceRect.width(),
                targetRects[i].height() / sourceRect.height()
            );

        painter->drawPixmapFragments(&pixmapFragment, 1, pixmap, hints);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtgui/qpainter-pixmapfragment.html `The sourceLeft, sourceTop, width and height variables are used as a source rectangle within the pixmap passed into the QPainter::drawPixmapFragments() function. The variables x, y, width and height are used to calculate the target rectangle that is drawn.`

Comment: @Amartel I've updated the question, please see if it is ok?

Comment: No, this is a bad solution. Why don't you show us an example of your old code, so we could help you to transform it?

Comment: @Amartel Because I wanted to ask more universal quiestion, but now I have added in Upd2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtgui/qpainter-pixmapfragment.html in Qt5 your code should look like this:

```
void ButtonSelector::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(option);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    //painter->drawPixmap(m_backGnd.rect(), m_backGnd);
    QRectF rectSrc = QRectF(m_backGnd.rect());
    QRectF rectTrg = boundingRect();
    QPainter::PixmapFragment fragment = QPainter::PixmapFragment::create(rectTrg.center(), rectSrc, rectTrg.width() / rectSrc.width(), rectTrg.height() / rectSrc.height());
    painter->drawPixmapFragments(&fragment,1,m_backGnd, QPainter::OpaqueHint);
    // I've change it to this call:
    // oldqt::drawPixmapFragments(painter, &rectTrg, &rectSrc, 1, m_backGnd, QPainter::OpaqueHint);
    // where oldqt::drawPixmapFragments is function from above

    // ... some other code unrelated to the question
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've written more universal function based on your answer (see Solution update in the question), please say, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation clearly states how to "adjust" the transition:

Taken from: http://qt.apidoc.info/5.1.1/qtgui/qpainter-pixmapfragment.html

> The sourceLeft, sourceTop, width and height variables are used as a source rectangle within the pixmap passed into the QPainter::drawPixmapFragments() function. The variables x, y, width and height are used to calculate the target rectangle that is drawn. x and y denotes the center of the target rectangle. The width and height in the target rectangle is scaled by the scaleX and scaleY values. The resulting target rectangle is then rotated rotation degrees around the x, y center point.